# How to make windows installation faster

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

My application is windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 support (one installer and use Visual studio 2015). Our installation iso is very large and contains

- Native, manage binaries with support content like
- .net framework
- C++ redistributables
- Content like image files, help documents and sample projects etc..

Installer is developed by Wix. but it takes so long time to install around 45 min. five years ago it was like 15 min. But when the content growth it takes undetectable time.

Now I'm thinking to improve the user experience and thinking is there any things can do for make the installation process faster.

So here I'm asking "Is there some things (practices) can help to make the installation faster in windows environment?"

*btw, I feel like this is a common question everyone face, and not sure someone asked before (I have search and couldn't find). If there is, Please someone help to point me there.*

Comment: Might be some help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344731/improving-performance-of-wix-msi-install-uninstall

Answer (score 2):

Apart from MSIFASTINSTALL, it depends on what you've got in your install. If you have COM registration that works by calling the Dll to register itself, then that can slow things down. If you have services that take a long time to initialize, that too. Anytime you call your own code is potentially an issue.  Have you taken a verbose log of the install and looked for the bottleneck areas?

Comment: Also the componentization strategy (higher files to component ratio), and reduction of number of custom actions can help.  .NET Framework install takes awhile, not much to do about that one.

Comment: Also assuming he's using a Burn bootstrapper (likely due to prereqs) building an MSI with external cabs can be faster as large MSIs can take awhile to be scanned by DEP.